# How to remove the following promise catches without making the code hang?

Tags: javascript, promise

The following code loops through some form fields. If the field is a file that has to be uploaded it runs an `api.uploadPhoto`function (setting the payload once the photos has been uploaded). If the field is a normal input when the payload is set directly:

```
formFields.forEach(field => {
  if (hasUploadFiles(field)) {
    uploadPhotoPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      uploads.queued.push(file)
      api.uploadPhoto(file, field).then(uploadedPhoto => {
        uploads.finished.push(field)
        if (uploads.queued.length === uploads.finished.length) {
          payload[field.name] = uploadedPhoto
          resolve()
        } else {
          reject()
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error:', error)
        reject()
      })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error:', error)
    })
  } else {
    payload[field.name] = field.value
  }
})

Promise.all([uploadPhotoPromise]).then(values => {
  // update action
}
```

The code works. However, all those `catch` make it look a bit messy.

I tried removed them but the code hangs if I remove any of them (the code inside `Promise.all` never runs). Why is this? And how to refactor this code without all those catch statements without making the it hang?

**Original code (plus Bergi's suggested modification):**

```
const buildingFormPromise = utils.mapDeep(this.buildingForm.schema, field => {
  if (!field.name) return // fields not in the database
  else if (utils.hasUploadFiles(field)) {
    utils.eachCall(field.value, (file, index) => {
      field.userId = this.user.id
      this.uploads.queued.push(file)
      this.$set(this.uploads.queued, index, { progress: 30 })
      return api.uploadPhoto(file, field).then(uploadedPhoto => {
        this.$set(this.uploads.queued, index, { progress: 100 })
        return loadImage(uploadedPhoto, () => {
          this.uploads.finished.push(field)
          if (this.uploads.queued.length === this.uploads.finished.length) {
            console.log('This runs after the code inside Promise.all')
            buildingPayload[field.name] = uploadedPhoto
          }
        })
      })
    })
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(buildingPayload[field.name] = field.value)
  }
})

Promise.all([buildingFormPromise]).then(values => {
  console.log('This runs before the files are uploaded')
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without making the it hang"?

Comment: Two things: 1) you don't create an array of Promises. You just have one `uploadPhotoPromise` over and over on each iteration. 2) You can't call `resolve()` in the first `catch()` since you don't have access to this function and you're outside the promise. This code most likely works because it doens't even get inside the `catch`, otherwise that's not how you use Promises.

Comment: There's more wrong with this code than the unnecessary `catch`es. I don't think that `Promise.all` with `uploadPhotoPromise` will work, the queuing logic is very fishy (it's not a queue, but it doesn't work in parallel either),  and you use the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). What do you want the code to actually do with the `formFields`?

Comment: @Bergi `the code inside `Promise.all` never runs`

Comment: @vassiliskrikonis Actually the `reject` in the catch is in scope, that's not a problem

Comment: @alex Yes, that's because the promise got rejected.

Comment: @Bergi just like my explanation: I want the code to wait for everything to be done (uploaded images and payload set) before triggering the update action.

Comment: @alex So you don't care whether they upload concurrently or sequentially, and you don't care about updating `uploads.queued` and `uploads.finished`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I don't care. And I'm only using `uploads.queued` and `uploads.finished` to know when I should trigger the update action.

Comment: @alex Ok, that attempt definitely failed. You currently are rejecting the promise when one file but not the last one are done. Gonna rewrite it in an  answer.

Comment: @Bergi I see, could you give me a sample code that fixes that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an array of all the promises into `Promise.all`, and you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). You can move the `.catch` to the very end if you don't want to handle individual upload failures.

```
var fieldValuePromises = formFields.map(field => {
  if (hasUploadFiles(field)) {
    return api.uploadPhoto(file, field).then(uploadedPhoto => {
      return payload[field.name] = uploadedPhoto;
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(payload[field.name] = field.value);
  }
});

Promise.all(fieldValuePromises).then(values => {
  // update action
}).catch(error => {
  // at least one upload failed
  console.log('error:', error)
});
```

Comment: Thanks I try it out! One question: so only the else statement need a `Promise.resolve`? What happens if all the fields are upload fields?

Comment: Yes, the if case already returns a promise, the result of chaining `then()` to `uploadPhoto()`. Strictly the promise in the else case isn't necessary, as `Promise.all` does resolve plain values as well, but it's better to have the `fieldValuePromises` contain only promises.

Comment: Weird, `Promise.all` runs before the files are uploaded. (I included the original code in my question).

Comment: Well, you don't collect your promises in `fieldValuePromises`, so `Promise.all` cannot await them… What is that `utils.eachCall` doing in there?! And what is `loadImage` doing with that callback, if it's asynchronous why does it not return a promise?

Comment: Here's a link with the relevant functions: https://gist.github.com/alexcheninfo/2660092edc1816854cd27e672341e3e0 (Thanks for your the time.)

Comment: So how should I modify the code to address this issue?

Comment: Make a `const buildingFormPromises = []`, and get your deep iteration to (immediately, before calling `Promise.all`) `push` all promises to it that you want to have awaited.

Comment: If you also want the `loadImage` to be awaited, then [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) it.